# Could not analyse class TYPO3 7.6.18 LTS (after upgrading from 6.2 LTS)

Tags: typo3, fluid, typo3-7.6.x

After upgrading from TYPO3 LTS 6 to LTS 7, my viewhelper extension classes are not found.

My classes are in the autoload_classmap.php.

ext_emconf.php

```
'autoload' => array(
    'psr-4' => array('Vendor\\ExtName\\' => 'Classes')
)
```

class

```
namespace Vendor\ExtName\ViewHelpers;

class VideoRenderViewHelper extends \TYPO3\CMS\Fluid\Core\ViewHelper\AbstractViewHelper {

    /**
     * 
     * @return string
     */
    public function render() {
        /*do something*/

        return $videoString;
    }
}
```

Fluid

```
{namespace v=Vendor\ExtName\ViewHelpers}
<v:videorender></v:videorender>
```

Can you see the problem?
Thanks

Comment: What is the path to the file? You do not need the autoload setting for the classes folder.

Comment: Sometimes it help to deinstall and reinstall extension.

Comment: I did uninstall / reinstall a lot of times and clear cache via install tool at each time.

Comment: My path is typo3conf\ext\extname\Classes\VideoRenderViewHelper.php

Comment: Please place your class in Classes/ViewHelpers/ and then reinstall the extensions. Then you don't need any further autoload definitions.

Comment: Soory, not working after uninstall, changing folder, install, clear caches from intall tool.  The path is Ok in autoload.php.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing
`<v:videorender></v:videorender>`
to
`<v:videorender />`
solved my problem.